# Accept an answer that answers the general question but didn't help in specific case

Tags: discussion

So I asked [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/202310/update-sverchok-tree-on-frame-change) yesterday about what I thought was my problem. I didn't provide any screenshots or blendfiles as I thought my problem was more general.
I got exactly the answer I was looking for but unfortunately it didn't solve my problem. BUT if another user searches BSE for the same answer, it may be exactly what they need. Should I accept the answer for this case even though it didn't help my sepecific problem but would have helped if I had the problem I thought I have and answered the question I asked?

Comment: Hi. If the answer didn't really solve your issue you'd be invited to answer it yourself stating what did. Nevertheless if the user helped you you can still upvote his answer for gratitude, despite not solving your issue directly. Having a positive score on his answer will likely help search engines direct future users towards the post, even it is not the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

If the answer didn't work for you, you don't have to accept it, let the uses who answered know why it didn't. But if any of the answers allowed you to discover what the problem was, you should update the question with the new findings or additional information, to make it more specific and useful.

If you found a solution by yourself, be kind enough to share it. Write an answer to your own question, so that other users can learn from you.